# Duda en consulta SQL Expresión SUM

Tags: sql-server

Buenas tengo una duda de la cual quiero aprender no quiero una solución si no una explicación

Si tengo una tabla ( la cual es ficticia no voy a agregar otros datos para hacerlo mas fácil)
Movimientos
idcuenta-ImporteMovimiento-TipoMovimiento
1-3000-Entrada
1-1000-Salida

estoy realizando una consulta (la cual me funciono adjunto al final)
para que me de el saldo actual
el cual seria 2000 ya que entró 3000 y salió 1000

me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de realizarla mas o menos asi..

```
select m.idcuenta,sum(m.ImporteMovimiento)-(select sum(ImporteMovimiento) from...)
from Movimientos m
```

Mi consulta larga:

```
select TOP 10 cuenta2.IdCuenta, cuenta1.ImporteMovim- cuenta2.ImporteMovim as Importe
from
(select * from Movimiento m
where  m.TipoMovim = 'E') as cuenta1,

(select * from Movimiento m
where  m.TipoMovim <> 'E' ) as cuenta2 where cuenta1.IdCuenta = cuenta2.IdCuenta order by Importe desc
```

Adicional no quiero abrir otro hilo ( en caso que sea necesario lo haré).
Me gustaría una breve explicación de las consultas Externas.
Saludos.

Comment: Quedo solucionado: no se si sea la mejor solución pero fue esta: select m.IdCuenta,sum(m.ImporteMovim)-
(select sum(f.ImporteMovim) from Movimiento f where f.IdCuenta=m.IdCuenta and f.TipoMovim <> 'E'
group by f.IdCuenta )
from Movimiento m
where m.TipoMovim = 'E'
group by m.IdCuenta
order by m.IdCuenta asc

Comment: publicalo como respuesta y explicalo para que así otros usuarios se beneficien de tu aporte

Answer (score 1):

Quedo solucionado: no se si sea la mejor solución pero fue esta:

```
select m.IdCuenta,sum(m.ImporteMovim)- (select sum(f.ImporteMovim) from Movimiento f where f.IdCuenta=m.IdCuenta and f.TipoMovim <> 'E' group by f.IdCuenta ) from Movimiento m where m.TipoMovim = 'E' group by m.IdCuenta order by m.IdCuenta asc
```

POR SUPUESTO QUE SI ALGUIEN QUIERE ACOTAR OTRA MANERA SERA BIENVENIDA! no hay una sola manera de hacer las cosas :)